# Initramfs, why is required for the mount root filesystem?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, mount, initrd

Why initramfs is needed in OS, why we can not mount the root filesystem without this file?
Why we can not mount root fileststem directly, but we need some intermediator (intramfs)?
And how to mount file system from kernel level (kernel side)?

Comment: We need it ? No, initial ramdisk is optionally .

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, you need to understand, boot process, & how the operating system  determines and understands the root fs (which stores the config,bins,data,etc for the rest of the services that come up, when the system is up), the drivers required for talking to the hardware (ex: the storage device or hard disk). Therefore you need to bundle up *at least* the basic *required* modules (like file-system and device drivers etc) in your initramfs, to bring up the system and mount the root fs. This is also a duplicate of [Is it possible to boot the Linux kernel without creating an initrd image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405083/initrd-and-booting-the-linux-kernel)